# How to use enum in 2 classes and store Java specific types in properties file

Tags: java, enums, properties, switch-statement

I am building an application to schedule a reminder every 60 mins, 30 mins, 15 minutes and so on. The user chooses the reminder interval (60 mins, 30 mins etc.)

**Question 1) I have a switch statement inside my class that checks the value of the reminderInterval. I have defined the values in an enum.**

```
//Enum defined in a separate file, not inside the classes SetupSchedule,ExecuteSchedule 

public enum ValidInterval {
HOUR, HALFHOUR, QUARTERHOUR, TENMINUTE, FIVEMINUTE 
}
```

I need to use this enum in two separate classes.

```
public class SetupSchedule {
public void setUpUserSchedule(String reminderInterval, boolean setSnoozeOff, boolean interruptIndicator) {
    switch(reminderInterval) {
        case HOUR :     someAction();
                        break;
        case HALFHOUR :someAction();
                         break;                     
        }
    }
}

public class ExecuteSchedule {
public void executeUserSchedule(String reminderInterval, boolean setSnoozeOff, boolean interruptIndicator) {
    switch(reminderInterval) {
        case HOUR :     someAction();
                        break;
        case HALFHOUR :someAction();
                         break;                     
        }
    }
}
```

STRUCTURE OF USER REQUEST:

```
public class UserSchedule {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @EnumValidator(enumClazz = ValidInterval.class)
    @NotBlank
    private String frequencyType;

    @NotBlank
    private boolean allowSnooze;

    @NotBlank
    private boolean interruptInd;
}
```

ERROR I AM GETTING: Eclipse is showing an error that HOUR, HALFHOUR cannot be resolved to a variable.

NOTE: **This is not a duplicate question** of how to use an enum since the enum is stored in a separate file; not in the same class it is being used in. I searched for an answer to this question, but could not find it.

Please do not mark as duplicate.

Comment: ValidInterval.HOUR.  You need to use the full enum name to reference it outside of it's class.

Comment: That is not valid Java. Cannot have `switch` statement directly in class. Must be in a method. Also, what is `reminderInterval`?

Comment: @BakonJarser Except in a `switch` statement on an `enum`, where the `case` value **must** be unqualified. Of course, it requires that the switch variable `reminderInterval` is actually of type `ValidInterval`, but regardless, for enums the case values are always unqualified.

Comment: @Andreas, reminderInterval is set by the user. It can take the values of HOUR, HALFHOUR, QUARTERHOUR, TENMINUTE, FIVEMINUTE

Comment: @user1478392 But *what* is it? A `String`? A `ValidInterval`? **Edit** the question and fix the code to be valid Java, and include a description or code showing what type `reminderInterval` is.

Comment: @Andreas, thankyou for your feedback. I have updated the code to valid Java code + included structure of user request.

Comment: `HOUR` is an enum constant, not a `String`. You can only use string constants in a `switch` statement on a `String` value, e.g. `case "HOUR":`

Comment: @Andreas, Thankyou for your response. So, there is no way I can use ValidInterval.HOUR inside the switch statement? Even if I declare a toString()  method inside the enum?

Comment: For your second question, create a new question. Don't ask multiple unrelated questions in a single question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write the name of the enum then the variable:

```
public class SetupSchedule {
    switch(reminderInterval) {
        case ValidInterval.HOUR:
            someAction();
            break;
        case ValidInterval.HALFHOUR:
            someAction();
            break;                     
    }
}
```

also you need to insert this switch inside a method you can't leave it among the class

Comment: If `reminderInterval` is a `ValidInterval`, then `case` values must be unqualified. If not, then qualifying with `ValidInterval` would never work ayway.

Comment: _also you need to insert this switch inside a method_ - The `switch`-statement of the OP is already inside the method `executeUserSchedule `.

Comment: @LuCio when i posted this answare it wasn't it was just like how i postet above

Comment: @Bonfra04 Checked the history of the question. You're right.